# Fourier transform of distribution function 1

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

I can't understand the third equation of the following equation series and I think I'm missing something pretty obvious. the $^\vee$ ist meant to represent the inverse fourier transform.
$$\hat{1}[\phi]=1[\hat{\phi}]=\int_\mathbb{R^n}\hat{\phi(k)}dk=(2\pi)^n \hat{\phi}^\vee(0)=(2\pi)^n \phi(0)    $$
I'd be very glad if someone could help me :)

Comment: The mean value integral over the domain is the 0 frequency component of the Fourier transform. It must be since all the sines and coses with non-zero frequency are mean-less.

Comment: This helped. Thanks. I'll write the answer mathematically, someone might find it helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing something simple indeed:
 
We know that $(\frac{1}{2\pi})^n\int_{\mathbb{R^n}}f(k)e^{ikx}dk=f^{\vee}(x) $ 
 which implies    $f^{\vee}(0)= (\frac{1}{2\pi})^n \int_{\mathbb{R^n}}f(k)   dk  $.

Replace f by $\hat{\phi}$ and you have the answer.
Props to mathreadler for his tip.